# Why is javascript executing if and else twice on Android, but not on PC?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I use a value in javascript, which is called slut. I put the value of slut into my html page. I use Javascript to change the menu, if it is a Mobile device, or not. But when i load the page on my phone, it shows the desktop menu. When i change the user agent of my pc browser, to the one my phone has, it shows the mobile menu. I have found out it is because, it executes both if and else on my phone. So my question is, why is it only doing that on my phone, and how to i make prevent it from doing so?

```
    if ( /webOS|Mobile|Mobile Safari|Opera Mobi|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) function slut() {
    var slutdiv= document.getElementById ("slut")
    var h = "";
    h += "</div>"
    h += "<div class=dropdown>"
    h += "  <button onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtn'>Menu</button>"
    h += "  <div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'>"
    h += "      <a href='../home/'>Home</a>"
    h += "      <a href='../downloads/'>Downloads</a>"
    h += "      <a href='../io'>Google IO</a>"
    h += "  </div>"
    h += "</div>"
    slutdiv.innerHTML=h; 
    sse1.buildMenu ()
}
    else function slut () {
    var slutdiv= document.getElementById ("slut")
    var h = "";
    h += "<div id='sse1'>"
    h += "  <div id='sses1'>"
    h += "     <ul>"
    h += "       <li><a href='../home/'>Home</a></li>"
    h += "       <li><a href='../downloads/'>Downloads</a></li>"
    h += "       <li><a href='../io/'>Google IO</a></li>"
    h += "     </ul>"
    h += "  </div>"
    slutdiv.innerHTML=h; 
    sse1.buildMenu ()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited Your code this will work for you

```
  if ( /webOS|Mobile|Mobile Safari|Opera Mobi|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  (function() {
        var slutdiv= document.getElementById ("slut")
        var h = "";
        h += "</div>"
        h += "<div class=dropdown>"
        h += "  <button onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtn'>Menu</button>"
        h += "  <div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'>"
        h += "      <a href='../home/'>Home</a>"
        h += "      <a href='../downloads/'>Downloads</a>"
        h += "      <a href='../io'>Google IO</a>"
        h += "  </div>"
        h += "</div>"
        slutdiv.innerHTML=h; 
        sse1.buildMenu ()
    })();
```

}

```
else
{
    (function() {
        var slutdiv= document.getElementById ("slut")
        var h = "";
        h += "<div id='sse1'>"
        h += "  <div id='sses1'>"
        h += "     <ul>"
        h += "       <li><a href='../home/'>Home</a></li>"
        h += "       <li><a href='../downloads/'>Downloads</a></li>"
        h += "       <li><a href='../io/'>Google IO</a></li>"
        h += "     </ul>"
        h += "  </div>"
        slutdiv.innerHTML=h; 
        sse1.buildMenu ()
}();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i get the error 'slut is not at function'